# My C file is writing random characters

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

I'm creating a battleship game with C, but in this function for place a new record on the records file, and keep it in order, the function writes in the file a lot of random characters.
Here are the structs:

```
typedef char nom_tipus [MAX_NOM];

typedef struct
{
    nom_tipus nom;
    int puntuacio;
} record_tipus;
```

here an example of a suposed resut:

> testdeunum 300asdf 151aaa 150bbb 149ccc 148ddd 147eee 146fff 145ggg 144hhh 143iii 142jjj 141kkk 140lll 139mmm 138nnn 137ooo 136ppp 135qqq 134rrr 133sss 132ttt 131uuu 130vvv 129"

and this is the final file:

```
Name 360mfuÿ<a    |ø`    H 300f   Iufu{<a    ` †lÔwúÒwÿÿÿÿ$   xø`        G»ðÛ—   akhud    ylu    ø` …thu¸?muàø` ¢ihu   ssgujsgu–   b   bu   ylu´ø` 0.buLkÔw\1«uL                151akhud    ylu    ø` …thu¸?muàø` ¢ihu   ssgujsgu–   b   bu   ylu´ø` 0.buLkÔw\1«uL                150b   bu   ylu´ø` 0.buLkÔw\1«uL                149cù` 0                   m1«uiÐw    (ú` L          ”   d                   (ú`          bu0ú`      “   e Œ®PØ€ù` B¤Òw0p@         €,@ àù` 4@ 0p@ 5n ú` ’   fHì¯      -@   @            ø1n p.n Ôù` ®jÔw  @ ‘   gkÔw\1«uL   <kÔwéïªu                148d                   (ú`          bu0ú`      “   e Œ®PØ€ù` B¤Òw0p@         €,@ àù` 4@ 0p@ 5n ú` ’   fHì¯      -@   @            ø1n p.n Ôù` ®jÔw  @ ‘   gkÔw\1«uL   <kÔwéïªu                147e Œ®PØ€ù` B¤Òw0p@         €,@ àù` 4@ 0p@ 5n ú` ’   fHì¯      -@   @            ø1n p.n Ôù` ®jÔw  @ ‘   gkÔw\1«uL   <kÔwéïªu                146fHì¯      -@   @            ø1n p.n Ôù` ®jÔw  @ ‘   gkÔw\1«uL   <kÔwéïªu                145gkÔw\1«uL   <kÔwéïªu                144h¼B3    0ú` $¨iuÄú` 8ú` Ãeu\ú` Pmup     Ðü` ¬iu   imu¬ú`        ’³iu€ú` 
   Pmu€ú` $¨iuý` ˆú` ÃeuŽ   jmup      143imu¬ú`        ’³iu€ú` 
   Pmu€ú` $¨iuý` ˆú` ÃeuŽ   jmup      142jmup      141k ¨ ý`         -ú`              B            Œ   l   (mu    ÿQ@ 6ïiu      ýÿÿÿxý` @   d   Cý` …üiu‹   mmumu    :þiuPmup ¨ ÿÿÿ”û` tý` xý` °ý`  P@ Š   n  °ý`           ”û`            ¤û`          ‰   o   muÜû       ÿ IÄfu+?amud       mu       ˆ   p   @þ` ðÑguŸBþÿÿÿôû` 1iumumud   „ü`  ü` 6ïiu‡   qü` ¤iu
      d   þ` …üiuø Xü` Õ§fuÜ§fu¯8a   †   r             Tü` Þ¬fuø ˜ü` UØfu   €Øfuo8a   …   sü` Õ§fuÜ§fu_8a   (mu              ¤ü` Þ¬fuø „   tØfu   €Øfu8a   (mu    8a$      ´ü`    Xý` ƒ   uBþÿÿÿ€Øfu…3iu   à 140l   (mu    ÿQ@ 6ïiu      ýÿÿÿxý` @   d   Cý` …üiu‹   mmumu    :þiuPmup ¨ ÿÿÿ”û` tý` xý` °ý`  P@ Š   n  °ý`           ”û`            ¤û`          ‰   o   muÜû       ÿ IÄfu+?amud       mu       ˆ   p   @þ` ðÑguŸBþÿÿÿôû` 1iumumud   „ü`  ü` 6ïiu‡   qü` ¤iu
      d   þ` …üiuø Xü` Õ§fuÜ§fu¯8a   †   r             Tü` Þ¬fuø ˜ü` UØfu   €Øfuo8a   …   sü` Õ§fuÜ§fu_8a   (mu              ¤ü` Þ¬fuø „   tØfu   €Øfu8a   (mu    8a$      ´ü`    Xý` ƒ   uBþÿÿÿ€Øfu…3iu   à 139mmumu    :þiuPmup ¨ ÿÿÿ”û` tý` xý` °ý`  P@ Š   n  °ý`           ”û`            ¤û`          ‰   o   muÜû       ÿ IÄfu+?amud       mu       ˆ   p   @þ` ðÑguŸBþÿÿÿôû` 1iumumud   „ü`  ü` 6ïiu‡   qü` ¤iu
      d   þ` …üiuø Xü` Õ§fuÜ§fu¯8a   †   r             Tü` Þ¬fuø ˜ü` UØfu   €Øfuo8a   …   sü` Õ§fuÜ§fu_8a   (mu              ¤ü` Þ¬fuø „   tØfu   €Øfu8a   (mu    8a$      ´ü`    Xý` ƒ   uBþÿÿÿ€Øfu…3iu   à 138n  °ý`           ”û`            ¤û`          ‰   o   muÜû       ÿ IÄfu+?amud       mu       ˆ   p   @þ` ðÑguŸBþÿÿÿôû` 1iumumud   „ü`  ü` 6ïiu‡   qü` ¤iu
      d   þ` …üiuø Xü` Õ§fuÜ§fu¯8a   †   r             Tü` Þ¬fuø ˜ü` UØfu   €Øfuo8a   …   sü` Õ§fuÜ§fu_8a   (mu              ¤ü` Þ¬fuø „   tØfu   €Øfu8a   (mu    8a$      ´ü`    Xý` ƒ   uBþÿÿÿ€Øfu…3iu   à 137o   muÜû       ÿ IÄfu+?amud       mu       ˆ   p   @þ` ðÑguŸBþÿÿÿôû` 1iumumud   „ü`  ü` 6ïiu‡   qü` ¤iu
      d   þ` …üiuø Xü` Õ§fuÜ§fu¯8a   †   r             Tü` Þ¬fuø ˜ü` UØfu   €Øfuo8a   …   sü` Õ§fuÜ§fu_8a   (mu              ¤ü` Þ¬fuø „   tØfu   €Øfu8a   (mu    8a$      ´ü`    Xý` ƒ   uBþÿÿÿ€Øfu…3iu   à 136p   @þ` ðÑguŸBþÿÿÿôû` 1iumumud   „ü`  ü` 6ïiu‡   qü` ¤iu
      d   þ` …üiuø Xü` Õ§fuÜ§fu¯8a   †   r             Tü` Þ¬fuø ˜ü` UØfu   €Øfuo8a   …   sü` Õ§fuÜ§fu_8a   (mu              ¤ü` Þ¬fuø „   tØfu   €Øfu8a   (mu    8a$      ´ü`    Xý` ƒ   uBþÿÿÿ€Øfu…3iu   à 135qü` ¤iu
      d   þ` …üiuø Xü` Õ§fuÜ§fu¯8a   †   r             Tü` Þ¬fuø ˜ü` UØf"
```

Here is the code:

```
#define MAX_RECORDS     25
#define MAX_NOM         50

bool emmagatzema_records(int punts, nom_tipus nom) {
    int i, j;
    char n;
    record_tipus records[MAX_RECORDS];
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("fitxer_records.txt", "r");
    i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_RECORDS) {
        j = 0;
        fscanf(f, "%c", &n);
        while (n != ' ' && j < MAX_NOM) {
            records[i].nom[j] = n;
            fscanf(f, "%c", &n);
        }
        fscanf(f, "%d", &records[i].puntuacio);
        if (punts > records[i].puntuacio) {
            if (i == MAX_RECORDS - 1) {
                records[i].puntuacio = punts;
                for (j = 0; j < MAX_NOM; j++) {
                    records[i].nom[j] = nom[j];
                }
            } else {
                records[i + 1].puntuacio = records[i].puntuacio;
                records[i].puntuacio = punts;
                for (j = 0; j < MAX_NOM; j++) {
                    records[i + 1].nom[j] = records[i].nom[j];
                }
                for (j = 0; j < MAX_NOM; j++) {
                    records[i].nom[j] = nom[j];
                }
                punts = 0;
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen("fitxer_records.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_RECORDS; i++) {
        j = 0;
        while (records[i].nom[j] != ' ' && j < MAX_NOM) {
            fprintf(f, "%c", records[i].nom[j]);
            j = j + 1;
        }
        fprintf(f, "%c", ' ');
        fprintf(f, "%d", records[i].puntuacio);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should use code formatting for the file contents, it's much easier to read.

Comment: @AB.S: please do not *fix* the code in the question, it makes the discussion inconsistent.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you are leaking an open file handle by not calling `fclose` at the end of the function.

Comment: That's true, i fixed it before, but it doesent help me.

Comment: for ease of understanding by us humans, 1) please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) with a blank line

Answer (score 2):

You never increment `j` when reading the strings one character at a time:

```
while (n!=' ' && j<MAX_NOM)
{
    records[i].nom[j++]=n;  // note `j` changed to `j++` 
    fscanf(f, "%c", &n);
}
```

This isn't really the usual way to read strings, of course.  You should use something like `fgets` instead.  And you really ought to check for I/O errors too.

Comment: thats true, but it continues giving random characters to the file. 
About the fgets... The profesors "baned" the fgets in this project.

Comment: Just to make sure this isn't undefined behaviour, you should include the definition of `struct record_tipus` in your question.  And probably `nom_tipus` too.

Comment: @AB.S: What a silly posture on their part! They should insist on proper code indentation and presentation instead.  Can you at least replace `fscanf(f, "%c", &n);` withe `int c = getc(f);` and properly test for `EOF`, or maybe use `fscanf(f, "%49s", records[i].nom)` to read the name in one step and test the return value.

Comment: Since you have no error handling, you may be corrupting the file when reading it from empty.  It looks like this program is designed to store a growing data structure on disk rather than in memory.  A problem you then have is that `records` is never initialised to anything.  Any calls to `fscanf` that fail will _NOT_ alter the memory you gave them.  So it may be that the structure is not adding new items correctly because it's copying uninitialised names all over the place (due to the ordering rules you've got).  Initialise the array and handle I/O failures, then try again.

Comment: First of all, errors will be treated from outside the function. The file will always be filled, either by old records or predefined records (aaa 10bbb 9ccc 8 ...).
About to initialise the array, i don't understand what are you meaning...

Sorry about my unkown, but i'm practically new in this world...